# What is the use of manifest.json in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, manifest.json

I deleted it while setting up a react project. After that project runs fine but it shows one error on the console (Line 1, syntax error)

Comment: The error is there, since your html still references the manifest.json but receives the react app when downloading it. You probably want to delete the ``<link rel="manifest" ...>`` tag in your ``public/index.html`` file

Answer (score 0):

It "provides information about an application such as name, author, icon or icons, description, and more." [Definition found here](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/progressive-web-apps/manifest-json/)

Another good explanation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

Here is a good [video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFsRylCQblw) for building PWAs (something manifest is often used to facilitate)